# Colours across Plots / Heatmaps in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, heatmap

I am creating a number of heatmaps in R, but I am having problems when it comes to keeping the colour scale consistent across graphs.

I find that the colours are scaled within a graph, is there a way to make colours consistent across graphs? Ie. So that that colour difference between a value of 0.4 and 0.5 is always the same?

*Code Example:*

```
set.seed(123)

d1 = matrix(rnorm(9, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.1), ncol = 3)
d2 = matrix(rnorm(9, mean = 0.8, sd = 0.1), ncol = 3)

mat = list(d1, d2)

for(m in mat)
  heatmap(m, Rowv = NA ,Colv = NA)
```

You'll note in the example that cell (2,3) the first graph is similar to cell (1,3) in the second, despite being ~0.8 different

Comment: In `heatmap` command (and other R heatmap packages in R) there is `breaks` and `col` arguments that you can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `ggplot2`, if you're open to not using base graphics:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Set common limits for color scale
limits = range(unlist(mat))
```

Here's the code for two separate graphs. The last line of code for each graph ensures that they use the same z limits for setting the colors:

```
ggplot(melt(mat[[1]]), aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(limits=limits)

ggplot(melt(mat[[2]]), aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(limits=limits)
```

[image]

Another option is to plot both heatmaps in a single graph using facetting, which automatically ensures both graphs are on the same color scale:

```
ggplot(melt(mat), aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value))   +
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ L1)
```

[image]

I've used the default colors here, but for either approach you can set the color scale to be anything you wish. For example:

```
ggplot(melt(mat), aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value))   +
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ L1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `image` function directly (`heatmap` uses `image`), though it will require some extra formatting to match the output of `heatmap`.  You can use `zlim` to set the color range.  Quoting from the [`?image`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/image.html) page:

> the minimum and maximum z values for which colors should be plotted,
>   defaulting to the range of the finite values of z. Each of the given
>   colors will be used to color an equispaced interval of this range. The
>   midpoints of the intervals cover the range, so that values just
>   outside the range will be plotted.

```
# define zlim min and max for all the plots
minz = Reduce(min, mat)
maxz = Reduce(max, mat)

for(m in mat) {
  image( m, zlim = c(minz, maxz), col = heat.colors(20))
}
```

To get closer to the formatting produced by `heatmap`, you can just reuse some code from the `heatmap` function:

```
for(m in mat) {
  labCol = dim(m)[2]
  labRow = dim(m)[1]
  image(seq_len(labCol), seq_len(labRow), m, zlim = c(minz, maxz),
    col = heat.colors(20), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
    xlim = 0.5 + c(0, labCol), ylim = 0.5 + c(0, labRow))
  axis(1, 1L:labCol, labels = seq_len(labCol), las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0)
  axis(4, 1L:labRow, labels = seq_len(labRow), las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0)
}
```

[image]

Using the `breaks` argument to `image` is another option.  It allows more flexibility than `zlim` in setting the breakpoints for colors.  Quoting from the help page, `breaks` is

> a set of finite numeric breakpoints for the colours: must have one
>   more breakpoint than colour and be in increasing order. Unsorted
>   vectors will be sorted, with a warning.